# Want Autonumbering as financial year then five digit number (razor, C#, linq) ex. 201400001 then 201400002

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I have several materials for consumption system.
with each consumption of material, I want to generate Number format as
Financial year then 5 digit number.

for example
this year 2014 first consumption 201400001 for item A.
for other item first consumption 201400001 for item B.
if Item A consume again 201400002.
and so on..

I have tried to make function

```
 public string GetAutoNumber(int itemid,string tablename, string fieldname)
    {
        ModelEntities en = new ModelEntities();
        long number=0;
        long autonumber=0;
        long finyear = 0;
        if (System.DateTime.Now.Month < 4)
        {
            finyear = (System.DateTime.Now.Year - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            finyear = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
        }
        switch (tablename)
        {
            case "table1":
                List<table1> tablelist = en.table1.Where(x=>x.itemid==id).OrderBy(x => x.order_no).ToList();
                table1 tb=tablelist.Last();
                **number=tb.order_no+1;**
                autonumber=finyear+number.ToString();
                break;
            case "table2":
                break;
        }
        return autonumber;
    }
```

**Code may work fine but it generate 20141.. how could I get 201400001.
Please note that if 123 is number I want 201400123.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
  string year = "2004";
  string num = "1";
  string result = string.Format("{0}{1}", year, num.PadLeft(5,'0')); // 200400001
```

Comment: Why is it so complicated? He is going to generate the year string, so just run padleft above it.

Comment: When new financial year start what could it be?. on new year started numbering again from 00001. One solution I have is get financial year from dbfield and some number too. but if I want to add this for new field I have to change db structure. which is not good for system design. Nice done!

Answer (score 1):

Read up on String.Format.

> +number.ToString();

tells to format the number without leading zeroes. Now you COULD tell it to use a specific format....

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

tells the standard formats.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

has custom numeric format "parts" to make your own strings.

It tells you:

"0": Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

So, you would do:

> .ToString ("{0:00000}");

to get 5 digits.

If I were you, though, I would construct it in one go:

> var formatted = String.Format ("{0:yyyy}{1:00000}", finyear, number)

Comment: When new financial year start what could it be?. on new year started numbering again from 00001. One solution I have is get financial year from dbfield and some number too. but if I want to add this for new field I have to change db structure. which is not good for system design. Nice done!

Comment: That is another question and we do not do that here. I answered the question you had - and if you have another one, post it as a question.